# how to close infowindow in google maps v3

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have tried to implement the last code at

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlinfo_v3

I want to have a cancel and close button.
So, i modified the code and uploaded it to

http://adsany.com/testclose.htm
(view source)

when i click on the map, a marker appears,

when I click on the marker, infowindow appears.

when I click on the cancel and close button, it closes the window, but a new marker appears.

So, i want to close the infowindow without creating a new marker.

Please suggest.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
    I hope this link will solve your Problem :-
    http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/single-infowindow/single-infowindow.html.


<html>
<head>
<title>Single Info Windows</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 13,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.789879, -122.390442),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

    var onMarkerClick = function() {
      var marker = this;
      var latLng = marker.getPosition();
      infoWindow.setContent('<h3>Marker position is:</h3>' +
          latLng.lat() + ', ' + latLng.lng());

      infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    };
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
      infoWindow.close();
    });

    var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(37.789879, -122.390442)
    });
    var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(37.787814,-122.40764)
    });
    var marker3 = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(37.767568,-122.391665)
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', onMarkerClick);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'click', onMarkerClick);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker3, 'click', onMarkerClick);
  });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
  body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
  }
  #map {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Demonstrates how to share a single info window on a map.</h2>
  <ol>
    <li>Click a marker to open a single info window containing the marker's position.</li>
    <li>Close the opened info window by clicking anywhere on the map.</li>
  </ol>
  <div id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. Can you please suggest me what to modify in my code at http://adsany.com/testclose.htm in order to use a cancel button in the infowindow? Thank you.