# how to close a infowindow on googlemap

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, infowindow

I am trying to find how to autoclose or/and to close a infowindow of a marker (google map).

I worked on that code but I do not understand why the close function does not close de infowindow. I have no errors on my Firefox console

Here is the code and your help will be appreciated

```
//Infowindow
google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function() {

/* the marker's content gets attached to the info-window: */
var info = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: this.content
});
info.close(); // IT DOES NOT CLOSE the open infowindow or all open

/* trigger the infobox's open function */
info.open(map,this); //This works

/* keep the handle, in order to close it on next click event */
//infos[0]=info;

});
```

Thank a lot

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to close infowindow in google maps v3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16666485/how-to-close-infowindow-in-google-maps-v3)

Comment: Is that not just because right after you close it, you open it???

Comment: No, unfortunately, none solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

I have similar code that seems to work when I add infowindow.close(), perhaps you can find the answer in mine:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, content) {
        return function() {
            map.panTo(marker.position);
            infowindow.setContent(content);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);       
            map.circle.setCenter(marker.position);
            infowindow.close();
        }
    })(marker, content));
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass two parameters when closing the infowindow. You can try the functions listed below. The close method is called on the click event to close the existing infowindow before opening the new infowindow on the marker.

This code will remove the infowindow as soon as you move your mouse away from the marker and it will open the infowindow when you click on the marker.

Try this out and let me know.

```
var info = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
content: this.content
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() { 
    info.close(map,marker); 
    info.open(map,marker); 
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
     info.close(map,marker); 
});
```